# Get mp3 Files from google drive

Tags: php, html, database, audio, mp3

I want to get mp3 files from Google drive, (Or if you can help me get a free data space at any other website, please help.)
I would like to create a website to list and able to play the mp3 songs.
Here is the beginning. This code is not the best method I need because there I can use only one single file, and have to edit and link a new src link.

Edit:Or, I have a MYSQL database with drive.google links to the mp3 files.

```
How can I get the URLs from there?

 <?php
 $input = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzvJ23h4c0mRblBacGktd0FPdDQ/view?
usp=sharing"; //song link

preg_match("/https:\/\/drive.google.com\/file\/d\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\//", 
$input, $match);

$GoogleDriveFileID = $match[1];
?>
<script>
var input = 
"https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzvJ23h4c0mRblBacGktd0FPdDQ/view?usp=sharing";

var res = input.match(/https:\/\/drive.google.com\/file\/d\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\//)

        var googleDriveFileID = res[1];
    </script>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/from-data">
</form>


 <audio controls>
<source src="http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=<?php echo 
$GoogleDriveFileID; ?>" type="audio/mp3">
<p>This browser does not support HTML5 audio</p>
</audio>
```

Comment: _"I would like to create a website to list and able to play the mp3 songs."_ [Here you go.](https://play.google.com/music/listen)

Comment: I didn't mean like this. I need a storage where is the mp3 files , and than read them out.

Comment: No settings to allow direct link to MP3? The link you put now in PHP is just for page (maybe checking source code can help you?)

Comment: @MátyásKatona ... Does this work if used as mp3 url in your PHP code : `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0BzvJ23h4c0mRblBacGktd0FPdDQ&authuser=0&export=download` (also might need to be logged-in to work? Could see my Google user name anyways) ... Finally just try using this one (more direct) : `https://doc-0k-5k-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/las40165m6l6qpcm8t0gcnoorsgh2qes/sgr7ii8r42q9ecoer9nafo9edt60n00p/1491775200000/06194350350854007440/15606690391915560764/0BzvJ23h4c0mRblBacGktd0FPdDQ?e=do%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bwnload` good luck